# Changing Json from API with Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a json code from API and I want to get new chat members with the code below but I only get the first two results and not the last (Tester). Why? It should itereate through the whole json file, shouldn't it?

```
r = requests.get("https://api.../getUpdates").json()

chat_members = []

a = 0
for i in r:
    chat_members.append(r['result'][a]['message']['new_chat_members'][0]['last_name'])
a = a + 1
```

Json here:

```
{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":213849278,
"message":{"message_id":37731,"from":{"id":593029363,"is_bot":false,"first_name": "@tutu"},"chat":{"id":-1001272017174,"title":"tester account","username":"v_glob","type":"supergroup"},"date":1537470595,"new_chat_participant":{"id":593029363,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"tutu "},"new_chat_member":{"id":593029363,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"\u7535\u62a5\u589e\u7c89\uff0c\u4e2d\u82f1\u6587\u5ba2\u670d\uff0c\u62c9\u4eba\u6e05\u5783\u573e\u8f6f\u4ef6\uff0c\u5e7f\u544a\u63a8\u5e7f\uff0cKYC\u6750\u6599\u8ba4\u8bc1\uff0c","last_name":"@tutupeng"},"new_chat_members":[{"id":593029363,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"\u7535\u62a5\u589e\u7c89\uff0c\u4e2d\u82f1\u6587\u5ba2\u670d\uff0c\u62c9\u4eba\u6e05\u5783\u573e\u8f6f\u4ef6\uff0c\u5e7f\u544a\u63a8\u5e7f\uff0cKYC\u6750\u6599\u8ba4\u8bc1\uff0c","last_name":"@tutu"}]}},{"update_id":213849279,
"message":{"message_id":37732,"from":{"id":658150956,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Rebecca","last_name":"Lawson"},"chat":{"id":-10012720,"title":"v glob OFFICIAL","username":"v_glob","type":"supergroup"},"date":1537484441,"new_chat_participant":{"id":65815,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Rebecca","last_name":"Lawson"},"new_chat_member":{"id":65815,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Rebecca","last_name":"Lawson"},"new_chat_members":[{"id":65815,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Rebecca","last_name":"Lawson"}]}},{"update_id":213849280,
"message":{"message_id":12,"from":{"id":696749142,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"daniel","language_code":"cs-cz"},"chat":{"id":696749142,"first_name":"daniel","type":"private"},"date":1537537013,"text":"/stat","entities":[{"offset":0,"length":5,"type":"bot_command"}]}},{"update_id":213849281,
"message":{"message_id":37740,"from":{"id":669620,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Ivan","last_name":"Tester"},"chat":{"id":-100127201,"title":"test account","username":"v_glob","type":"supergroup"},"date":1537537597,"new_chat_participant":{"id":669620191,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Ivan","last_name":"Tester"},"new_chat_member":{"id":669620191,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Ivan","last_name":"Tester"},"new_chat_members":[{"id":669620191,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Ivan","last_name":"Tester"}]}}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine has come up with a solution:

```
for i in l['result']:
    chat_members.append(i['message']['new_chat_member']['first_name'])
```

To sum up: Iterate through 'result' with no positional arguments

Answer (score 4):

Because you iterate over the entire response dict. The top level only has two items, so that's what you iterate over. Note that you don't actually use the iterator variable, and you have a completely unnecessary separate counter.

Instead, you should be iterating over the result dict:

```
for result in r['result']:
    if "new_chat_members" in result['message']:
        chat_members.append(result['message']['new_chat_members'][0]['last_name'])
```

Comment: when I paste your code I get this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/D...ram.py", line 18, in <module>
    chat_members.append(result['message']['new_chat_members'][0]['last_name'])
KeyError: 'new_chat_members'`

Comment: Because the third element in the results list doesn't have a "new_chat_members" key, for some reason; it has "entities" instead. You'll need to check your API documentation to find out why one element has a different structure from the rest.

Comment: Its a Telegram bot and it sends all kinds of data :/ can I turn it into a string and look through it with regex then?

Comment: No, that would be the wrong thing to do. You can do something like `if "new_chat_members" in result['message']:`

Comment: `for result in r['result']:`
    `if "new_chat_members" in result['message']:`
        `chat_members.append(result['message']['new_chat_members'[0]['last_name'])`
    `else:`
        `break`
like this?

Comment: `if 'first_name' in l['result'][0]['message']['new_chat_members'][0]:`
    `chat_members.append(l['result'][0]['message']['new_chat_members'][0]['first_name'])`
`elif 'first_name' in l['result'][1]['message']['new_chat_members'][0]:
    `chat_members.append(l['result'][1]['message']['new_chat_members'][0]['first_name'])`

Your solution works, thanks a lot! But a loop would be better I guess